# How can I get the same result of an in-place modification of a uin8_t[] in a Swift Objective-C function using an UnsafeMutablePointer<Uint8>?

Tags: c, swift, pointers

I'm having an issue where in Swift my Int array is unchanged (I'm learning Swift as I go).

In C:

```c
uint8_t buffer[size]

// function( uint8_t *buffer,)

function(buffer)
```

In Swift what I think I'm supposed to do (this is a function written in C using Swift's @objc and bridging header):

```swift
var buffer = [ UInt8 ](repeating: UInt8(0), count: 47)
let cbufferpointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: cbuffer.count)
cbufferpointer.initialize(from: buffer, count: buffer.count)

// samefunction( UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>! buffer)

samefunction(cbufferpointer)

var arr = Array(repeating: 0, count: 47)
            
var i = 0
for element in buffer
{
    print(element)
    Arr[i] = Int(element)
    i+=1
}
```

The buffer comes out with zero change – just a bunch of zeros. I would have expected at least the first two to be changed.

Any suggestions?

I tried to set hex number in the buffer in Swift. However, the buffer is unchanged. Is this because I'm using Swift structs wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did figure it out. seems that swift has a neat way of dealing with c data types. when defining c data types or pointers you can simply use & and swift will convert it to an Unsafe pointer  very interesting. similar to giving the address.